# How do I alter the file link of an uploaded image in edit/create node form?

Tags: 7, uri

When I upload an image in drupal, a file icon and a file name that links it to original file is created.

For example, I upload "foo.jpg" then

```
 <a href=path-to-file>foo.jpg</a>
```

is generated.

I want to change the path-to-file url because it's put putting base_url() + path-to-file which results in Not Found. I'm using amazon s3 for file storage.

I only want the path-to-file url without the base_url. Can anyone share some wisdom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try implementing your own [theme_file_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/theme_file_link/7).

> Returns HTML for a link to a file.
>
> Parameters
>
> $variables: An associative array containing:
>
> file: A file object to which the link will be created. icon_directory:
>   (optional) A path to a directory of icons to be used for files.
>   Defaults to the value of the "file_icon_directory" variable.

Put this into your theme's template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_file_link($variables){
  $file = $variables['file'];
  $icon_directory = $variables['icon_directory'];

  $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
  $icon = theme('file_icon', array('file' => $file, 'icon_directory' => $icon_directory));

  // Set options as per anchor format described at
  // http://microformats.org/wiki/file-format-examples
  $options = array(
    'attributes' => array(
      'type' => $file->filemime . '; length=' . $file->filesize,
    ),
  );

  // Use the description as the link text if available.
  if (empty($file->description)) {
    $link_text = $file->filename;
  }
  else {
    $link_text = $file->description;
    $options['attributes']['title'] = check_plain($file->filename);
  }

  return '<span class="file">' . $icon . ' ' . l($link_text, $url, $options) . '</span>';
}
```

Clear the cache, and then modify the code.

I would also investigate [Amazon S3 Stream Wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3_api)